# Coq as part of continuous integration

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, coq

In my current project we use Java and Coq. We have a continuous integration set up, using maven. We want to check coq files as part of it. I.e. we need:

- Download and install coq locally if it isn't installed (like maven does with frameworks like gwt, etc)
- Check that coq files are correct

Did anybody try setting up this? How can this be done?

Comment: I wonder what do you prove with Coq? Some properties of java code?

Comment: We prove correctness of algorithm which we them manually translate to Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend automate that from your CI Build. Instead, it looks more like a Machine Configuration Dependency.

In cases like this, it is worth it to rely in tools like Puppet and Vagrant in order to ensure your Development Environment conforms to a given context, so your code needs to deal with this as either a premise or - better yet - ensure it is available in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but I have a different answer.

I have a similar CI setup that needs to install build tools. In some cases, such as on bitbucket, I pre-build a docker image containing the tools and update the build configuration each time I update the tools. In bitbucket, this works well because the source code of the package being built points to the particular docker image version to use to build it, which ensures that older builds can still be built, assuming the older docker images are retained.

Otherwise, I just script the installation of the tools using wget or curl to download as necessary.